# Reset all buttons inner.text and background.color with Reset button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reset all the buttons inner.text back to original value (1,2,3) and background.color back to grey with a reset button.
I think something wrong with the for loop because when i place i=0 i < 3, it works. I need it to be btns.length, because i will be adding more buttons later.
What i did wrong with the "YES" button code ?

[image]

```js
// Get the Reset that opens the ResetModal
var reset = document.getElementById('ResetModal');
var rst = document.getElementById('reset'); 
rst.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "block";
}
//Hit "NO" to turn off modal window
var rstno = document.getElementById('resetno'); 
rstno.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "none";
}
// Hit "YES" to reset all button to initial value
var rstyes = document.getElementById('resetyes'); 
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) { 
    rstyes.onclick = function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("b"+i);
    btn.innerText=i;
    btn.style.background="#D3D3D3";
    reset.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "none";
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');
// target value
var TV = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
// Each button click => open modal 
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].onclick = function() { 
    TV.setAttribute('startbtn', this.id );
    modal.style.display = "block"; 
  }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function() {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
//Arithematic Operator Control
function checkValue(){
  var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal');
  var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById( TV.getAttribute('startbtn') );
  var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
  var targetValue = parseInt(TV.value);
  
  if (value < targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red' ;
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else if (value >= targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else{
    buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = ''
  }
  modal.style.display = "none" ;
  return false;
}
```

```css
#b1,
#b2,
#b3 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#b30,
#b31 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#inputtarget {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1;
}

#trigger {
  height: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
#b1:hover,
#b2:hover,
#b3:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

#b1:active,
#b2:active,
#b3:active {
  background-color: silver;
  box-shadow: 1px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}

#modal1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Reset (background) */

.reset {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Reset Content/Box */

.reset-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}

#resetyes,
#resetno {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close1 {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close1:hover,
.close1:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
<!-- All Buttons in Matrix Form Production -->
<button id="b1" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:100px">1</button>
<button id="b2" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:100px">2</button>
<button id="b3" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:100px">3</button>
<input id="inputtarget" class=numberonly value=0 type="number" min="0" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style="position:absolute; left:55px; top:160px"><br>
<input id="reset" type=button value=Reset style="position:absolute; left:170px; top: 180px">
<input id="trigger" type=button value="Change Target Value" onclick="return CheckBVWithTV()" style="position:absolute; left:165px; top: 530px">
</div>
<!-- The Modal Box 1-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" >

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
    <input id="modal" type="number" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style=font-size:20px><br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" class=submit_on_enter onclick="return checkValue()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>
  <!-- The Reset Box -->
<div id="ResetModal" class="reset">
    <!-- Reset content -->
    <div class="reset-content">
      <span class="close1">&times;</span>
      <p>Are you sure ? <br> This Action cannot be undone.</p>
      <input id=resetyes type="button" value="YES">
      <input id=resetno type="button" value="NO">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `for loop` inside your `rstyes.onclick` function. You only have one reset yes button, therefore you would not need 3 click functions for that one button. Then in your `for loop` start from 1 and set it to end at `btns.length + 1` since your btns array index starts at 0 and your buttons ids start at 1.

```js
// Get the Reset that opens the ResetModal
var reset = document.getElementById('ResetModal');
var rst = document.getElementById('reset');
rst.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "block";
  }
  //Hit "NO" to turn off modal window
var rstno = document.getElementById('resetno');
rstno.onclick = function() {
    reset.style.display = "none";
  }
  // Hit "YES" to reset all button to initial value
var rstyes = document.getElementById('resetyes');
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');

    rstyes.onclick = function() {
      for (var i = 1; i < btns.length + 1; i++) {
        var btn = document.getElementById("b" + i);
        btn.innerText = i;
        btn.style.background = "#D3D3D3";
        reset.style.display = "none";
      }
    };
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
  reset.style.display = "none";
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button:not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');
// target value
var TV = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
// Each button click => open modal 
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onclick = function() {
    TV.setAttribute('startbtn', this.id);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function() {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //Arithematic Operator Control
function checkValue() {
  var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal');
  var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById(TV.getAttribute('startbtn'));
  var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
  var targetValue = parseInt(TV.value);

  if (value < targetValue) {
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value;
  } else if (value >= targetValue) {
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value;
  } else {
    buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = ''
  }
  modal.style.display = "none";
  return false;
}
```

```css
#b1,
#b2,
#b3 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#b30,
#b31 {
  background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #999;
}

#inputtarget {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1;
}

#trigger {
  height: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#b1:hover,
#b2:hover,
#b3:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

#b1:active,
#b2:active,
#b3:active {
  background-color: silver;
  box-shadow: 1px #666;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}

#modal1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Reset (background) */

.reset {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Reset Content/Box */

.reset-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
}

#resetyes,
#resetno {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close1 {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close1:hover,
.close1:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- All Buttons in Matrix Form Production -->
  <button id="b1" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:100px">1</button>
  <button id="b2" style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:100px">2</button>
  <button id="b3" style="position:absolute; left:130px; top:100px">3</button>
  <input id="inputtarget" class=numberonly value=0 type="number" min="0" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style="position:absolute; left:55px; top:160px">
  <br>
  <input id="reset" type=button value=Reset style="position:absolute; left:170px; top: 180px">
  <input id="trigger" type=button value="Change Target Value" onclick="return CheckBVWithTV()" style="position:absolute; left:165px; top: 530px">
</div>
<!-- The Modal Box 1-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
    <input id="modal" type="number" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57' ; style=font-size:20px>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" class=submit_on_enter onclick="return checkValue()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- The Reset Box -->
<div id="ResetModal" class="reset">
  <!-- Reset content -->
  <div class="reset-content">
    <span class="close1">&times;</span>
    <p>Are you sure ?
      <br> This Action cannot be undone.</p>
    <input id=resetyes type="button" value="YES">
    <input id=resetno type="button" value="NO">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

Length begins at 1, and the loop you are using begins at zero. **you either need to modify the use of i in your loop or begin the button IDs at b0**. The way your html and js is currently written, the loop does nothing during the first iteration. I would recommend changing the ids to begin at b0 and use the updated for loop above.

If you change the button IDs to begin at zero, you should be able to keep using the condition `i < btns.length` in the loop.

Happy programming!

Comment: Hi FlyingCactus,
i dont have button with id begin at b0, i dont think i want my Button with innertext "1" to be id b0. It is not correlate to each other because when i have button 31, my button id is 30. Not quite right